# Using a for loop in batch with modulus operator

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

```
for /L %%i in (1, 1, 100) do (           
    SET VAR=%%i %% 5
    set /a CAL=%VAR% %% 5
    echo %CAL%
)
```

Hey guys here is the simple code above, im trying to take the index and use % 5 on each increment.

the command line is giving me:

```
SET VAR = 100 % 5
set /a CAL = % 5
Missing operand.
```

What exactly am i doing wrong? thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Much better explanation of what you intend to do is required. Trying to work out what you want from code that doesn't work becomes a guessing game.

The first thing you should realise is that you need to separate statements with `&` OR put them on separate lines, otherwise the ENTIRE expression on the right-hand side is assigned to `VAR`.

I'll assume what you meant was

```
for /L %%i in (1, 1, 100) do (
 SET VAR=%%i %% 5 
 set /a CAL=%VAR% %% 5 
 echo %CAL%
)
```

Now we can't tell from this what you really want to achieve. Perhaps you wanted to set `val` to the value of the expression `%%i %% 5` You need the `/A` switch

```
for /L %%i in (1, 1, 100) do (
 SET /A VAR=%%i %% 5 
 set /a CAL=%VAR% %% 5 
 echo %CAL%
)
```

Now - the next line, Are you trying to set `CAL` to the value of `%VAR% %% 5` ? Well - a couple of problems with that - first, `VAR` would be 0..4 so setting `CAL` to that `VAR %% 5` would set `CAL` to 0 regardless.

The second problem is more major, and extends to the next line.

A FOR loop is parsed from the FOR through to the ending parenthesis. At PARSE-TIME, any `%var%` is replaced by the THEN-CURRENT value of the variable. ***THEN*** the code is executed.

Since neither `var` nor `cal` were set at PARSE time, what would be executed is

```
for /L %%i in (1, 1, 100) do (
 SET /A VAR=%%i %% 5 
 set /a CAL= %% 5 
 echo 
)
```

So you'd get a 'missing operand' error on the `SET CAL` line and `ECHO` would duly report "Echo is OFF" (or ON as the case may be.

TO overcome these problems, you need to add change a few things...

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /L %%i in (1, 1, 100) do (
 SET /A VAR=%%i %% 5 
 set /a CAL=!VAR! %% 3 
 echo !VAR! !CAL!
)
```

Note here the `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` which establishes a mode where `%var%` still returns the PARSE-TIME value but `!val!` returns the RUN-TIME value - as it changes. Since `VAR` will vary between 0 and 4, I've changed the calculation of `CAL` to allow the change to be seen, and the ECHO reports the RUN-TIME values of both `var` and `cal`

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter. What happened was, when i copied my code from the .bat file and submitted it the formatting changed, making the code all on one line. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The following two codes lead to the same results. The first one uses DelayedExpansion and is much faster, the second goes without `VAR`:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%i in (1, 1, 100) do (
    SET /a VAR=%%i %% 5
    set /a CAL=!VAR! %% 5
    echo !CAL!
)
```

.

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /L %%i in (1, 1, 100) do (
    set /a CAL="(%%i%%5)%%5"
    call echo %%CAL%%
)
```

Comment: Thank you Endoro! Very useful